# How to host node api on macos using xampp apache web server and mysql?

Tags: node.js, apache, xampp, hosting, android-host-api

I was working on a windows project and created some node apis and I have hosted them in local windows pc using **iis server** successfully.

After that I had one more requirement of hosting same node api on mac os local server similar to iis server. I was able to run the same project using xampp and started services mysql database and apache web server and it was working fine.

But, I couldn't find a way to host this node api on my local macbook server anyway.

Can anyone help me or suggest a possible workaround?

Thanks